# Can we do type conversions using unions?

Tags: c, gcc, unions

Consider the following union:

```
union{
 uint32_t a;
 uint64_t b;
};
```

Both `a` and `b` reside in the same memory area. If we initialize the 32 bit integer `a` to some value, how is it possible to get `b` (when `b` was not initialized)? Does it mean that the compiler internally converts a to b

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler doesn't convert anything and doing that is undefined behavior.

Comment: Setting `a` you are writing 4 byte in your memory as `int`. Accessing `b` you are reading 4 bytes of memory as `float`: what's the problem?

Comment: @LPs I am on 32 bit platform.

Comment: So........ I'm not getting you

Comment: I want to convert 32 bit integer to 64 bit integer and vice versa.

Comment: So why `float`? `uint32_t a = 10; uint64_t b = a; `

Comment: Sorry I will edit the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136556/discussion-between-bionix1441-and-lps).

Comment: BTW you cannot use a union to convert members with different sizes.

Comment: *Aliasing* is completely different from *conversion*.  What are you really asking here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra bytes in the `uint64_t` will have an unspecified value.

From section 6.2.6.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *7* When  a  value  is  stored  in  a  member  of  an  object  of  union  type,  the  bytes  of  the  object representation that do not
>   correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take
>   unspecified values.

And section 6.5.2.3:

> *3* A postfix expression followed by the `.` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object.  The
>   value is that of the named member, <sup>95)</sup> and is an lvalue if
>   the  first  expression  is  an  lvalue.   If the  first  expression 
>   has  qualified  type,  the  result  has the so-qualified version of
>   the type of the designated member
>
> *95)*   If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object,
>   the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is
>   reinterpreted as  an  object  representation  in  the  new type  as 
>   described  in  6.2.6  (a  process  sometimes  called  "type punning").
>   This might be a trap representation.

The only time this is allowed is if you have a union of one or more structs and each struct has an initial member of the same type.

From section 6.5.2.3:

> *6* One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several  structures  that  share  a 
>   common  initial  sequence  (see  below),  and  if  the  union object 
>   currently  contains  one  of  these  structures,  it  is  permitted 
>   to  inspect  the  common initial part of any of them anywhere that a
>   declaration of the completed type of the union is  visible.   Two 
>   structures  share  a common  initial  sequence if  corresponding 
>   members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths)
>   for a sequence of one or more initial members.

Here's an example where this might be useful:

```
union sockadddr_u {
    struct sockaddr sa;
    struct sockaddr_un sun;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
}
```

These structures store information on sockets of different types.  Most of the members differ, but the first member of each is of type `sa_family_t` whole value tells you the socket type.  This allows you to inspect the first member of any of these members to figure out which of the members contains meaningful data its internal members.

Comment: Is it really UB? I mean: isn't it a platform dependent and implementation defined behavior?

Comment: An unspecified value is not an indeterminate one. The standard also explicitly allows type punning via union http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note95 And it's very much implementation defined (and not UB), if the target type has a trap representation.

Comment: @dbush Thank you  ` common initial part of any of them` means two structures having the same fields (same types and same number for all fields of the structure). But why would I have a union of similar structures, what would be the use of it ?

Comment: @Bionix1441 Not all fields, just the initial fields.  See my update.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the clarification.  Updated to reflect.